# Order By with have_post wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have ids of some posts id array that have higher priority for me.

Now on listing all posts i want that array ids should come first then all other ids post.

I have logic set for that order by like i have array with two ids (15,19) then i want those two post first then other all id posts should come.

My logic is below and it works well.

**ORDER BY CASE 
WHEN id IN(15,19) THEN 0
ELSE id
END**

But how can i add this logic with **have_posts** loop order by.

Please help me.

Comment: Is this a custom query? Are these IDs static, meaning you know them an they're not going to change? Are you relying on any meta for your ordering? Can you post the code of your loop?

Comment: Ya when i add this with custom query it works.Ya my ids are static.They are not going to change.I am not relying on any meta.i want ordering with post-id.Code is below <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> I do all the stuff within this loop.


    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

Comment: Maybe you can use `post__in` for a [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) - view this [support article](_listing_year)

Answer (score 0):

Thinking fast about it I would make two loops, one with the posts you want fixed in the beginning and the second with the rest of the posts like this:

```
 $fixed = array(8,14); 
 //gets only the posts with IDs 8 and 14
    $fixed_args = array(
        'post__in' => $fixed
    );
    $fixed_query = new WP_Query($fixed_args);

    if($fixed_query->have_posts()){
        while ($fixed_query->have_posts()){
            $fixed_query->the_post();
            the_title();
            the_content();                
        }
    }
    //excludes the posts with IDs 8 and 14
    $query_args = array(
        'post__not_in' => $fixed
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query($query_args); 
    if($the_query->have_posts()){
        while ($the_query->have_posts()){
            $the_query->the_post();   
            the_title();
            the_content();     
        }
    }
```

I don't know if there is a way to do this in just one simple loop, but I will look into it and update if I find anything.